# Where to put the custom exception classes?

Tags: c++, class, exception, header-files

Suppose that I have a class which you can see below (**Please read the comments too**):

`Foo.h`

```cpp
#pragma once

namespace Bar
{

class Foo
{
public:
    inline Foo( );

private:
    char c;
    inline static const std::unordered_set<char> CHAR_SET {'/', '\\', '|', '-'};

    friend class Invalid_C_Exception;
};

} // end of namespace Bar
```

And I have:

`Foo.cpp`

```cpp
#include "Foo.h"

using namespace Bar;

inline Foo::Foo( )
{
}

class Invalid_C_Exception : public std::exception
{
public:
    virtual const char* what( ) const throw( )
    {
        std::stringstream ss;

        ss << "Invalid_C_Exception: { ";

        // compiler gives an error here because of usages of CHAR_SET
        for ( auto it = Foo::CHAR_SET.cbegin( ); it != Foo::CHAR_SET.cend( ); ++it )

        {
            ss << "'" << *it << "', ";
        }

        return somehow_save_the_C_string(ss.str());
    }

} Invalid_C_Exc;
```

#### 1st question:

Is the existence of the global `Invalid_C_Exc` variable ok?

#### 2nd question:

Why does the compiler blame me for `CHAR_SET` being private while trying to compile `Foo.cpp`?

The custom exception class, despite being a friend of class `Foo`, is not able to access `CHAR_SET`?

#### 3rd question:

Where should I put these custom exception classes? In a separate header and source file, but under the same namespace?

I was undecided, so I put the declaration and implementation in the source file `Foo.cpp` because the exception class is designed to work for the class `Foo`, so they're related to each other.

Comment: Do you really need custom exceptions?  There are plenty of already made exception types [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception) that cover pretty much most of the things I have ran into.

Comment: code is all about details. When some line isnt relevant you should rather remove it than asking to ignore it

Comment: @NathanOliver custom exceptions are a good practice. In "Clean Code" Robert C. Martin explains why (Java is used as examples, but reasoning applies also for C++).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1st question: Is the existence of this variable ok?

Globals are not generally a great idea, and since exception objects are copied to dedicated exception storage when thrown, I don't see any use for this particular global.

> second question is that why does the compiler blame me for CHAR_SET being private

You have *defined* a class `Bar::Foo` and *declared* its friend class `Bar::Invalid_C_Exception` ... but you haven't touched those at all in the implementation file. You've just declared a new *and unrelated* `Invalid_C_Exception` in the global namespace.

Remove the `using namespace Bar` and wrap everything below the includes in `namespace Bar { ... }` same as in the header. Or explicitly write `Bar::Foo` and `Bar::Invalid_C_Exception` everywhere if you prefer.

The `using namespace` directive makes names *from* the namespace visible in the enclosing scope. It doesn't suck everything added to the enclosing scope afterwards *back* into the namespace. How would that work if you have more than one `using namespace` directive? And why would `using namespace std;` ever be allowed?

> 3rd question: Where should I put these custom exception classes?

Well, you can't put the definition in your implementation file if you want anyone to be able to use it. Just put the class definition in the header, and leave only the definition of `Bar::Invalid_C_Exception::what` in the implementation file.

Whether they go in the *same* header & implementation file as the class they're friends with is up to you, it doesn't really matter.

> 4th question: how many questions should I ask per question?

One. It's called a question, not a questionnaire.

Comment: I also have a few static constexpr variables inside namespace Bar in Foo.h. Now if I want to put these exception classes in a seperate .h and a .cpp file then their functions won't be able to access those file-static variables of **Foo.h**. What is the solution? Should I take those variables out of Foo.h and put them inside Foo.cpp and also make them global so that other .cpp files can access them too? Is this a good idea?

Answer (score 1):

There is a big difference between

```
friend class Invalid_C_Exception;
```

and

```
friend Invalid_C_Exception;
```

The latter expects that `Invalid_C_Exception` already exists *somewhere accessible* and makes that symbol a friend of `Foo`. The former declares a new symbol `Invalid_C_Exception` **in the enclosing scope** and makes that the new friend.

Meaning you have made `Bar::Invalid_C_Exception` a friend of `Foo`, not the global `::Invalid_C_Exception` you have defined later which is still not a friend. The fact that `Bar::Invalid_C_Exception` will never exist is irrelevant.

Regarding your first question, `Invalid_C_Exc` is a global variable, by default it has external linkage. If you use it only in this translation unit(.cpp file), make it `static` or put it into an anonymous namespace.
I would recommend not being lazy and write its definition on a separate line, it's much more clearer that way. Other than that, you can use it just fine, it is initialized before `main` begins and lives until the end of the program.

Regarding your third question. Wherever you want, I would generally advise for one `.hpp` per one exception type or tightly-grouped pack of them. Putting it into `.cpp` makes catching it hard.